# Dummy Values for Date Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have to modify the date column so as to filter data accordingly:

```
table_id - type - date
 1       -  1   - 1/2/2001   
 2       -  1   - 2/3/2002
 3       -  2   -
 4       -  3   -
 32      -  1   - 5/3/2011
 34      -  1   - 1/2/2013
```

We would like to identity all the table_ids which have type=1 with the same date values as available, but we want to differentiate the type=2 and type=3 which are null values.

My solutions:

- for type-2 populate future dates 8/9/2016
- for type-3 populate fixed date value 99/99/9999

Is this a good approach? What is a good technical, optimal solution to do this?

Can I populate the date column with values 99/99/9999 (I believe I cannot do this but I want to be sure) or what are the usual dummy values that I can use for this?

Comment: What does this mean: "which have type=1 with the same date values as available"?  Can you clarify why `NULL` is problematic?

Comment: Use `02/02/9999` and `03/03/9999` for type=2 and type=3

Comment: table_ids(1,2,32,34) have type_column value=1 and they can be identified by the date values that they are currently assigned..My problem here is want to be able to identify all the three types(type column values=1,2,3) using the date column values. So all the valid dates can be identified type 1, all the future dates which are not equal to 99/99/9999 can be identified as type 2, others can be type 3...hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you use only a dates and ignores a time values, then  it's possible to encode an information about types in a time part of date values.

Suppose, we have this example table:

```
create table my_table(
  table_id    number,
  type_field  number,
  date_field  date

);
```

Based on them it's possible to encode `type_field` data into `date_field` if number of types less than number of seconds in one day (< 86400):

```
select
  (
    nvl(date_field,to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')) 
    + 
    type_field/24/60/60
  ) date_with_type_as_seconds
from 
  my_table;
```

And after selecting data you can separate date part from time part and get both fields:

```
with encoded_values as (
  select
    (
      nvl(date_field,to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')) 
      + 
      type_field/24/60/60
    ) date_with_type_as_seconds
  from my_table
)
select
  (
    ( 
      to_number(date_with_type_as_seconds 
      - 
      trunc(date_with_type_as_seconds))
     )
       * 24 * 60 * 60
  )                    as type_field,

  decode( trunc(date_with_type_as_seconds),
    to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd'), null,
    trunc(date_with_type_as_seconds) 
  ) 
                       as date_field
from 
  encoded_values;
```

**[<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/575bc/19)**